# Issue in web scraping using Selenium and driver.get()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape this url but the url I enter in the driver.get() gets changed when the program runs and chrome page is opened.
What can be causing it to change?

I want to open this link and get specific things but the url changes and it displays error because this class doesnot exist on the changed url.

Here's my code:

```
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/pk/one-bahawalpur.html?aid=378266&label=bdot-Os1%2AaFx2GVFdW3rxGd0MYQS541115605091%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap22%2C563%2C000%3Aac%3Aap%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atikwd-334108349%3Alp1011080%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm%3Appccp%3DUmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YYriJK-Ikd_dLBPOo0BdMww&sid=0a2d2e37ba101e6b9547da95c4a30c48&all_sr_blocks=41645002_248999805_0_1_0;checkin=2022-11-10;checkout=2022-11-11;dest_id=-2755460;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=41645002_248999805_0_1_0;hpos=1;matching_block_id=41645002_248999805_0_1_0;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;sr_pri_blocks=41645002_248999805_0_1_0__1120000;srepoch=1668070223;srpvid=e9da3e27383900b4;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl")


print(driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="d2fee87262"))
```

The url after chrome page is opened is as follows:
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=378266&label=bdot-Os1%2AaFx2GVFdW3rxGd0MYQS541115605091%3Apl%3Ata%3Ap1%3Ap22%2C563%2C000%3Aac%3Aap%3Aneg%3Afi%3Atikwd-334108349%3Alp1011080%3Ali%3Adec%3Adm%3Appccp%3DUmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YYriJK-Ikd_dLBPOo0BdMww&sid=63b32ef8c1d53ae0613d71baf62c3e56&checkin=2022-11-10&checkout=2022-11-11&city=-2755460&group_adults=2&group_children=0&highlighted_hotels=416450&hlrd=with_av&keep_landing=1&no_rooms=1&redirected=1&source=hotel&srpvid=e9da3e27383900b4&room1=A,A,;#hotelTmpl

Comment: There is no such element on that page. Even when I open it manually and nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is changed by the site. You can not change its behavior. It is redirecting users with new sessions to the search instead of the page of a hotel.
As a workaround I can suggest to click the hotel name in search:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Hotel One Bahawalpur"]').click
```

put this line between the line that opens the page and the line that finds the element.
Also I recommend you to add a line `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` after the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)`. This will improve your scraper's stability as it makes selenium wait while an element appears on the page.

Comment: The click method solved the new page opening problem. But how do i select elements from the new page now? Do i have to write something or its already done? Because when I try to access element from new page, the program says it doesnot exist. I have tried the wait method aswell.

Comment: Ah, I see. When you click the link, the page opens in a new tab. So right after clicking the link you can switch to this new tab using this code: `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`

Comment: After this I wrote: 'print(driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="d2fee87262"))'  to access element on new page. But it says no such element exists.

Comment: That's strange. So now you have these two lines `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, and '//div[text()="Hotel One Bahawalpur"]').click'
'driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`
between the lines `driver.get...` and `print...`, right?

Comment: Yes. The link opens just fine but when I try to access something from the new page, it says no such element found. I have checked this by printing current urls before and after click() and switch... both urls are same :(

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. Just now I changed driver.window_handles[1] to 2 and it worked. Thank you so much for the help. You have done me a huge favour. God bless you.